# Texstudio version 2.10.12: How to stop \ch autocomplete to \chapter

Tags: texstudio, chemformula

I would like texstudio to stop autocompleting my \ch command to \chapter.Can you please suggest what to do ?

I have already made the changes suggested in previous posts (image attached)[image]

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: you mean if you type `\ch` it fills automatically to `\chapter`? or that `\chapter` appears in the autocompleter box when you type `\ch` and you don't want that behaviour? please clarify. also, there's no TXS 2.10.12, presumably you mean 2.12.10.